# Apache - Zeppelin build failed on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am so stuck in this. I have followed each and every single instruction here (https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin)
to install Apache-Zeppelin. I need this for Spark.

Below are various required applications installed in UBUNTU (VM)

```
hduser@HDPMaster:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)

hduser@HDPMaster:~$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-339
Java version: 1.7.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

hduser@HDPMaster:~$ node --version
v0.10.25
```

Cloned  Zeppelin from Git Hub

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin.git
```

Initially, I had Maven 3.0 version. One of the threads suggested to have a version > 3.3..Installed the latest version (3.3.9).

executed the below command which is still failing

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-1.5.2 -Phadoop-2.7.1

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Zeppelin ........................................... SUCCESS [ 32.205 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter .............................. SUCCESS [ 36.457 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine .................................. SUCCESS [ 21.499 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [ 51.142 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark .................................... SUCCESS [01:01 min]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  3.089 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  2.736 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  2.813 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Hive interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [ 12.357 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Phoenix Interpreter ............... SUCCESS [ 15.315 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter ................... SUCCESS [  4.681 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Tajo interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  6.417 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink .................................... FAILURE [  6.133 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Cassandra ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Elasticsearch interpreter ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-13T06:12:12-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 122M/341M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "spark-1.5.2" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "hadoop-2.7.1" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.4:compile (scala-compile-first) on project zeppelin-flink: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.4:compile failed: Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0.4, org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.13.1, org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.13.1, org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.13.1, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-flink
```

No idea where to go from here. Are there any changes required in any of the settings in zeppelin folder ? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason behind it but this problem got solved. I just ran the below command in the morning and build was successful

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

Not sure if there is a logic behind that but if someone knows please share that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cloned zeppelin from git, then you need to go to the 'master' folder(in command line) and then run the following command :

`mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-1.5.2 -Phadoop-2.7.1`